# Overriding grails.views.default.codec='html' config back to 'none'

Tags: grails, encoding, groovy, expression, gsp

In Grails (<2.3), if I leave `grails.views.default.code='none'` in the grails Config.groovy, it's up to me to HTML encode my expressions explicitly in the GSP files: `${myValue?.encodeAsHTML()}`.

If I set `grails.views.default.codec='html"` in the Config.groovy, then the HTML encoding happens automatically for every expression: `${myValue}`.

My question: If I set the default to `'html'`, how do I get back to `'none'` for one expression when I don't want the HTML encoding behavior?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If default encoding level is set to html using

***grails.views.default.codec = "html"***

then for removing the html encoding for one expression in a page you can use

***${raw(expression)}***

Comment: Only available for Grails >= 2.3 see http://mrhaki.blogspot.fr/2013/11/grails-goodness-generating-raw-output.html. The question targets Grails < 2.3. See John Flinchbaugh answer below.

Answer (score 64):

To summarize the various levels at which the codec can be applied:

Set Config.groovy's `grails.views.default.codec='html'` to get HTML escaping by default on all `${expressions}` in the application.

Then when you want to default a whole page back to none, use the directive:

```
<%@page defaultCodec="none" %>
```

or

```
<%@ defaultCodec="none" %>
```

To disable HTML encoding for one expression in a page that is otherwise defaulting to HTML, use `<%=expression%>` notation instead of `${...}`.

Comment: This solution no longer works.  Instead, you will need to use the 'raw' method:    `${raw(expression)}`

Comment: I'll have to revisit this with new Grails. They probably made it much easier.

Comment: @A.J.Brown Still works if you're still using <2.3 ;)

Comment: Oops, I thought in Grails 2.4.3 nothing of the above is working but I was wrong. Just do not use "println" in the expression section - this will encode it nevertheless!

Comment: @A.J.Brown thanks for `${raw(expr)}`, it's exactly what I was looking for. Any idea on where it's documented? I mean it ***has*** to be documented somewhere, almost a year after it was introduced right?

Comment: @Tobia, it's in the docs (at least the 2.3 docs), but it's appearance is very short lived: http://grails.org/doc/2.3.0.M1/guide/security.html

Answer (score 7):

Try using ${raw(myValue)} , you do not need to declare page codecs etc

Answer (score 5):

From [GRAILS-1827](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-1827), it looks like you can override the default codec for a specific page with

```
<%@ defaultCodec="HTML" %>
```

or

```
<%@page defaultCodec="HTML" %>
```

in some versions (see the referenced issue).

Answer (score 1):

I may have a solution. I'm not sure how accepted it is, though.

I can set the default codec for expressions to HTML, but then use <%=myValue%> notation in GSP instead of ${} expressions to get the unescaped values onto the page.

Comment: You've said more than this in your other answer. This one doesn't add anything.

Comment: @cdeszaq Look at the dates. The fuller answer was later. (And they were both from 2009 (and your comment was a year before mine).) :|

Comment: @CharlesWood My point is that this inferior answer should be deleted. My apologies for not making this more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Write your own tag and write the expression direct to the output stream:

```
class YourTagLib {

    static namespace = "x"

    def unescaped = { attrs, body ->
        out << attrs.value
    }

}
```

Use it in your GSP:

```
<x:unescaped value="${yourexpression}"/>
```