# Why doesn't grails.views.default.codec default to "html"?

Tags: security, grails, gsp

The Grails Config.groovy setting `grails.views.default.codec` specifies the default codec used to encode data within `${...}` in Grails views.

This config setting can take any of the values `none` (no filtering required), `html` (to avoid XSS-attacks) and `base64` (has no real-world use-case that I know of).

The Grails default is `none` (no filtering).

Questions:

- Are there any compelling technical reasons not to use the safer option "html"?
- When do you choose to go with the default option of "none" in your Grails projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A question on similar topic [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337464/overriding-grails-views-default-codechtml-config-back-to-none).  I don't claim big expertise on this, but I imagine.  Why it's not html by default is strange to me. I found [GRAILS-2945](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-2945), where this was proposed but ultimately rejected, without too much explanation.   There is also some more information in [GRAILS-1827](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-1827), when the issue was first implemented.