# Greek characters in Grails with message function

Tags: grails, internationalization, character

I'm trying to use internationalization with grails

everything works fine on browser, Greek characters display properly, but when I open the page source of the browser to check the generated html code, the Greek characters display like this:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="&Epsilon;&nu;&omicron;&iota;&kappa;&iota;&alpha;&zeta;ό&mu;&epsilon;&nu;&alpha; &delta;&omega;&mu;ά&tau;&iota;&alpha;"/>
```

The issue above arises only when I use the the message **function** , i.e.

```
content="${message(code:'keywords' )}"
```

When I use the **tag** message,

```
<pre>
 <g:message code="test" />
</pre>
```

Greek characters are shown correctly on the source code of the browser.

Any help? I found this page:
http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/symbols.html for Greek symbols and html entities

I suppose Google's spiders wont be happy with the Greek version of the site

Answer (score 0):

It is probably the setting for `grails.views.default.codec` in your `Config.groovy`.  If it is `html` then everything in a Groovy block `${ }` will be encoded with HTML entities, but the `<g:message/>` tag won't be, as it doesn't apply the `encodeAsHTML()` call.

You can override this setting with [in page settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337464/overriding-grails-views-default-codechtml-config-back-to-none) so that the parts of your gsps which need escaping are still encoded.