# How Do I Save and Display HTML in Grails Using the CKEditor?

Tags: sql-server, grails, ckeditor

I'm using the CKEditor plugin of Grails and while I can store the HTML content from CKEditor to the database, I can not render it properly in the view.

What I'm getting in the view is the HTML escaped and not as mark-up content.

```
<p> sdfsdfsadf</p> <p> asdfasdfasdf</p> <p> asdfasdfasdf</p> <p> &yen;</p>
```

When I want:

```
sdfsdfsadf
asdfasdfasdf
asdfasdfasdf
¥
```

How do I get the stored data to render properly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337464/overriding-grails-views-default-codec-html-config-back-to-none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [John Flinchbaugh's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1755532/20770) on [this question about codecs and encodings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1337464/20770):

> To disable HTML encoding for one expression in a page that is
>   otherwise defaulting to HTML, use `<%=expression%>` notation instead
>   of `${...}`.

Answer (score 6):

Migrated to Grails 2.4 and after some head scratching, found `<%=expression%>` is deprecated.

Using the new syntax `${raw(expression)}` solved my issue.

Comment: You made my friday happier :D

Comment: Only solution for Grails v2.5.2 too, the other methods are indeed deprecated. Thnx!

Answer (score 2):

try ${instance?.attribute?.decodeHTML()}