# How can I disable Grails createLink codec (encoding)?

Tags: security, grails, encoding

Updated Grails from `2.2.0` to `2.2.4`.
Before: `http://localhost:8180/sub:favorites`
After: `http://localhost:8180/sub%3Afavorites`

As you can see Grails encodes URL's params by default. How can I disable it and encode it manually?

Comment: I believe you are willing to change encoding settings (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337464/overriding-grails-views-default-codec-html-config-back-to-none

Comment: I'm experiencing exactly the same problem after update from 2.2.0 to 2.2.5. My solution (for now) will be decode the URL manually as @fedor-belov said below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chances are high that there is an easier way. But if there isn't you can do the following:

Grails registeres a bean named `grailsLinkGenerator`. This bean is used for creating links (`createLink(..)` or `<g:createLink />`) within the the application. I think the default implementation is a [CachingLinkGenerator](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/mapping/CachingLinkGenerator.html) which is a subclass of [DefaultLinkGenerator](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/mapping/DefaultLinkGenerator.html) which again implements the interface [LinkGenerator](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/mapping/LinkGenerator.html).

You could extend one of these classes and override the bean in `resources.groovy`:

```
 grailsLinkGenerator(YourLinkGenerator) {
   ..
 }
```

Comment: This behaviour is hard coded in `RegexUrlMapping` class, method `encode` since 2.2.2. I've created ticket to change it - http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10477 . For now the only way to solve this problem is to manually decode URL