# Can I use a variable in the page directive?

Tags: grails, gsp

Given this:

```
render(template: 'someTemplate', model: [codec: 'none'])
```

It seems that I cannot use the `codec` variable in the `page` directive. Tried these:

```
<%@page defaultCodec="codec" %>
<%@page defaultCodec="${codec}" %>
<%@page defaultCodec=codec %>
```

Is there a way to pass the coded in the model?

Answer (score 0):

About this..

**UPDATE**

```
<g:set var="defaultCodec"   value="${codec}" />

<%@page defaultCodec="${defaultCodec}" %>
```

Comment: what happens then ? what is the value of "defaultCodec"

Comment: How do you use default defaultCodec ? What make you say it is not working ?

Comment: I expect no codec to be used for my page (just like putting `<%@page defaultCodec="none" %>` into the page), but after adding the suggested answer the default `XML` codec is still used.

Comment: Ok I didnt understood your question, I think I get it now did you check this post ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337464/overriding-grails-views-default-codec-html-config-back-to-none

Comment: I did see that question but it is not what I'm after either. I want to  pass a `String` from the controller (as part of the `model`) and set the `defaultCodec` for that entire page to the codec passed in the `model`. Basically, I want to set the `defaultCodec` based on some logic in the controller.