# How to set gsp element attribute value from controller

Tags: grails, groovy, rtf, gsp

I have a field that can store data with html tags and format intact. For example: Field A has following data:

```
Comment 1 by User 1 01/01/2014: Jhyap 
<br> 
Comment 2 by User 2 01/05/2014: Momo kasto mitho
<br>
Comment 3 by User 3 01/05/2014: Launa k garney aba
```

Currently on using `<g:fieldValue bean="${Instance}" field="Field A"/>` the gsp displays field as 
`Comment 1 by Saila 01/01/2014: Jhyap<br>Comment 2 by Kaila 2 01/05/2014: Momo kasto mitho<br>Comment 2 by Kaila 2 01/05/2014: Momo kasto mitho<br>`

Is it possible to display this field's value in GSP like this:

Field A:

Comment 1 by Saila 01/01/2014: Jhyap
 Comment 2 by Kaila 2 01/05/2014: Momo kasto mitho
 Comment 3 by Maila 3 01/05/2014: Launa k garney aba

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of avoiding **Cross Site Scripting (XSS)** Grails escape all the html content in `${}` expression in GSPs, therefore you can use

```
${raw(htmlString)}
```

For more see [Cross Site Scripting (XSS) Prevention](http://www.jellyfishtechnologies.com/render-html-string-gsp/)

Comment: Thank you Abdullah! Any insights on what to do if our grails app version is 2.2.5 since this method is only available since 2.3?

Comment: To disable HTML encoding for one expression,use <%=expression%> notation instead of ${} for version <2.3 for further reference you can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337464/overriding-grails-views-default-codec-html-config-back-to-none

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the fieldValue tag you could just print out the value directly. Like this:
`${Instance['Field A']}` or maybe `${Instance.'Field A'}`.

Comment: Hey David. Thanks for the response. 
${Instance.'Field A'} worked!